# can't connect to SQL named instance with native client 11 (SQLNCLI11)

Tags: sql-server, database-replication

I'm trying to create an SQL replication with publisher = SQL 2008 R2 and a named instance SERVER\UNIVERSE and a subscriber = SQL 2012.

replication is working fine on other SQL host.
on SQL 2012, I got trouble to connect to distributor. I've narrow down to the OLE connection. and found weird results with latest sql native client

```
$conn = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
$conn.ConnectionString = Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=SERVER\UNIVERSE;Trusted_Connection=yes;
$conn.Open()
```

return following error

```
Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "Login timeout expired
A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing
a connection to SQL Server.
```

if I try to connect without the named instance, it succeed

```
$conn.ServerVersion
10.50.2500
```

but the weird thing, if I perform the exact same commands on one of my other subscriber (SQL 2008R2 with SQLNCLI10), the named connection works as expected ...

```
$conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=SERVER\UNIVERSE;Trusted_Connection=yes;"
```

is it a bug ? I can't easily move the named instance to default one ...

**edit**

test udp

[image: 1434 port open]

port of the named instance (default SQL port 1433)
[image]

sql server browser running
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect to a named instance using the instance name, SQL Server first must query the SQL Server Browser service to determine the port number of the named instance.  Make sure the SQL Server Browser service is running and UDP port 1434 is allowed through the firewall (as well as the named instance port).

Comment: thanks for quick hint (btw I wasn't aware of that :)), I've edited the main post with the checks I've performed related to SQL Service Browser ... still no luck...

Comment: If SQL Server is listening on the 1433 default port, specify just the host name.  You don't need to specify the instance name when the instance is listening on port 1433.  The client will attempt to connect to port 1433 by default, named instance or not.

Comment: I'm in an SQL replication where the replication distributor itself sends the distributor end point and only accept the full named instance (even if exist on default port as well...). it was the first thing that I've tried to change without success...
found a solution with microsoft premiere guy...

Answer (score 0):

ends up that my udp test on port 1434 wasn't fully really successful (wrong positive), open but filtered. so wrong initial assumption on my side. still a little bit surprise that it was working well on another server, I set it up in the past and fairly sure I didn't ask for explicit port opening... but maybe firewall rules changed in the meantimes.

So we fixed quickly our issue by adding an alias, working now as expected ...
[image]